# How can I find out which functions can be run on an expression?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to programmatically find out which functions in a module could possibly apply to a particular expression.

Let's make this concrete.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Test where

-- we'll import template-haskell from Lens
-- so we can create prisms automatically for our 'AST'
import qualified Control.Lens.TH as LTH

--- some 'AST' in a toy language

data CExp
  = CLit Int -- a literal integer
  | CAdd CExp CExp -- addition
  | CMul CExp CExp -- multiplication
  | CSub CExp CExp -- subtraction
  deriving Show

-- an eval for our AST

eval :: CExp -> Int
eval exp =
  case exp of
    CLit i -> i
    CAdd e1 e2 ->
      eval e1 + eval e2
    CMul e1 e2 ->
      eval e1 * eval e2
    CSub e1 e2 ->
      eval e1 - eval e2

-- a function to build a sum using add with our AST, from a list of Int values

listToSums :: [Int] -> CExp
listToSums =
  foldr CAdd (CLit 0) . fmap CLit

-- here we make prisms for looking at particular values
-- in the CExp AST

LTH.makePrisms ''CExp

-- let's have an expression:
theList1 :: CExp
theList1 = listToSums [1..38]
```

Now, at this point, I'd like a function that can give me a list of all the top level functions of a particular module (including this one) that are able to be applied to the expression `theList1`. This will include the prisms that were created with `makePrisms`.

It would be fine if it uses the hint library's `Interpreter` monad. I've been experimenting with it a bit, and while I can get a list of all of the definitions at the top level of any module, and I can find the types of them, too (more or less), I'm a bit lost about how to pass an expression in as an argument to these functions then check if those expressions will typecheck.

If I can do that, I can run filter across all of the functions in a module, which lets me find out which ones are applicable.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-0.6.0/docs/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html#v:typeChecks

Comment: Legendary! Not sure how I missed this. Thank you... I have `funs = map unwrapFun . filter isFun $ exports` and then `typeCheckFuns <- filterM typeChecks (fmap (++ " theList1") funs)` and that works great. Put your answer there, and I'll accept it.

Comment: I *was* kind of hoping there might be a better way, but I guess not.

Comment: I wrote it up as an answer. (There's a handy trick when you want to filter a list for values which match a constructor, which is to put the pattern in a list comprehension's binder, as I have done with `Fun` in the second line of the function's body.)

Comment: Yeah, the List monad do notation works like that, too. `do { Just z <- [Just 1, Just 2, Nothing, Just 5]; return z }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hint](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-0.6.0) has a function called [`typeChecks :: MonadInterpreter m => String -> m Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-0.6.0/docs/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html#v:typeChecks), which tells you whether the expression in the string is well typed in the interpreter's context.

```
fnsAccepting :: MonadInterpreter m => String -> m [Id]
fnsAccepting expr = do
    moduleContents <- getLoadedModules >>= traverse getModuleExports
    let importedFns = [fn | exports <- moduleContents, Fun fn <- exports]
    filterM (\fn -> typeChecks $ fn ++ " " ++ parens expr) importedFns
```

Comment: I didn't try this whole example specifically, but `typeChecks` works for what I was after (at least it's one way to do it). I was hoping there might be a nicer / better way to do this, but I guess not.

Comment: I'd prefer a more dynamic style. I'd prefer not to have to typecheck them all if possible. Just like I *could* typecheck an expression with an Integer against a function that takes Integers to find out its first argument type, or I could check the type explicitly and see if it matches, but Haskell isn't *quite* dependently typed yet, and doesn't seem to offer these kinds of functionalities.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to look at the types of the functions in scope and see if their argument type matches the type of the expression? Rather than type check the whole application as I have done above? But HM systems do their type checking by unification, not by straightforward syntactic equality like most OO systems. If the input expression is, say, `'q'`, searching only for functions whose argument type is `Char` will exclude perfectly valid applications like `id 'q'` because `id :: a -> a`'s parameter type (`a`) is not `Char`.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that. Sorry for the overly simple example — I was trying to make it easier to understand. What I'm trying to say is that just like I can search a list for something that matches a set of values, if types were values, I would theoretically be able to search a list of string references to top level declarations which get reified and checked without leaving the expression space of the module said code is in. Maybe I'm dreaming. :) But I'll see how I go with this.